# Limit Pagination using javascript in php and creating customized design

Tags: javascript, pagination, limit

Can anyone help me out? I am rusty at Pagination using javascript and would like to implement it on my php website. I am trying to make something similar to the example Pagination on this [website:](http://blog.polymorph.at/105/finished-scripts/prev-next-1-2-3-page-link-php-function), but like i said i am really rusty, and it does not limit my results. for example. it looks like this: | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | ... |All the pages |, but I would like it to be more like the website like example can someone please help me out?

```
$num_of_result = mysql_num_rows($result);

$results_per_page = 10;
$pageNum = intval($_POST['pageNum']);
if($pageNum == "")
    $pageNum = 0;


$limit = " LIMIT ".($pageNum*$results_per_page)." , ".($results_per_page)." ";
$sql .= $limit;

echo "
<script>
function setpage(num){
    document.pageForm.pageNum.value = num;
    document.pageForm.submit();

}
</script>";

echo "<form action='search_results.php' method='post' id='pageForm' name='pageForm' >";
foreach($_POST as $name => $value){
    if($name != "pageNum"){
        if(is_array($value)){
            foreach($value as $element){
                echo "<input type='hidden' name='".$name."[]' value='$element'>";
            }
        }
        else
            echo "<input type='hidden' name='$name' value='$value'>";
    }
}
echo "<input type='hidden' name='pageNum' id='pageNum'>";
//echo show page links
if($num_of_result > $results_per_page){
    //Get total pages
    $pageCount = ($num_of_result / $results_per_page);

    for($i=0; $i < $pageCount; $i++){
        if($i == $pageNum)
            $html[] = "<strong>".($i+1)."</strong>";
        else
            $html[] = "<a href='javascript: setpage($i);'>".($i+1)."</a>";
    }

    echo "Page: ";
    echo @implode(' | ',$html);
    if( $pageNum < ($pageCount-1) )
        echo " | <a href='javascript: setpage(".($pageNum+1).");'>Next Page</a>";

}
```